# Find an invertible matrix $B$ such that all eigenvectors of $B$ are scalar multiples of a given vector.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $u = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}    1  \\    0  \\    0  \\
>  \end{array}} \right)$. Find an invertible matrix $B$ such that all
>   eigenvectors of $B$ are scalar multiples of $u$.

My attempt: Let $\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   \alpha   \\
   0  \\
   0  \\
\end{array}} \right)$
 be an eigenvector of B corresponding to eigenvalue $\lambda$. Then $B\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   \alpha   \\
   0  \\
   0  \\
\end{array}} \right) = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   {{b_{11}}} & {{b_{12}}} & {{b_{13}}}  \\
   {{b_{21}}} & {{b_{22}}} & {{b_{23}}}  \\
   {{b_{31}}} & {{b_{32}}} & {{b_{33}}}  \\
\end{array}} \right)\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   \alpha   \\
   0  \\
   0  \\
\end{array}} \right) = \lambda \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   \alpha   \\
   0  \\
   0  \\
\end{array}} \right) \Rightarrow \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   {\alpha {b_{11}}}  \\
   {\alpha {b_{21}}}  \\
   {\alpha {b_{31}}}  \\
\end{array}} \right) = \lambda \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   \alpha   \\
   0  \\
   0  \\
\end{array}} \right)$. Therefore $b_{11}=\lambda$ and $b_{21}=b_{31}=0$. I don't know how to find the other entries of $B$...

Answer (score 1):

If $\lambda\ne \mu$ eigenvales, then the corresponding eigenvectors must be *indepent*.

Hence, I see 2 possibilities for solving the exersize:

1. In case, we work over $\Bbb R$, we can set 2 other eigenvalues to be not reals, but complex conjugated to each other, for example $B$ restricted to the $y,z$ plane is a *rotation*.
2. Consider a *Jordan block*.

Comment: Thanks but this problem is excerpted from my past-year exam papers, and neither of what you've mentioned is covered in my course, so I'm not supposed to do it those ways. :(